# How could I make a force field effect on a player?

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft

I want to make a player Invunerable to damage and all knockback for a certain period of time (except for fall damage). My rpoblem is that the bukkit runable is not wroking as intended:

```
  public class WeaponEvents implements Listener {
private Elemental_weapons plugin;
ArrayList<UUID> forceFieldArray = new ArrayList<UUID>();

@EventHandler
public void onplayercrouchevent(PlayerToggleSneakEvent event) {
    boolean issneaking = event.isSneaking();
    Player player = event.getPlayer();
    if (issneaking==true) {

        if (player.getInventory().getChestplate().equals(Weapons.chestplate)) {

            forceFieldArray.add(player.getUniqueId());
            Bukkit.broadcastMessage(String.valueOf(forceFieldArray));
            new BukkitRunnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Bukkit.broadcastMessage("no more");
                    forceFieldArray.remove(player.getUniqueId());
                }
            }.runTaskLater( plugin, 200L);
            while (forceFieldArray.contains(player.getUniqueId())) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: Use events. For the duration of your invulnerability you need to first register, then capture any knockback and damage events and cancel/consume them so that the default Minecraft behaviour does not occur. Note that this can break other mods/plugins if the priority or order of events is in the wrong order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do this by having an array, say

`ArrayList<UUID> forceFieldArray = new ArrayList<UUID>();`

then whenever you want to activate your player's forcefield use a BukkitRunnable to set a delayed task.

```
forceFieldArray.add(player.getUniqueId());
new BukkitRunnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        forceFieldArray.remove(player.getUniqueId());
    }
}.runTaskLater(plugin, 200L);
```

Just remember that the '200L' in there is ticks, 20 ticks to a second so 200L is 10 seconds. This adds the player to the array, then in ten seconds it'll remove the player. Using this you can now use that array to check if players have the force field active.

```
public void onPlayerDamage(EntityDamageEvent e) {
    //Check if entity is player
    //Create player variable
    if(e.getCause() == DamageCause./*[Damage type you want to cancel]*/) {
        if(forceFieldArray.contains(player.getUniqueId())) {
            e.setCancelled(true);
        }
    }
}
```

This way you could even make a config with a list in there, have all the types of damage you want the forcefield to block then just above the ifs bring that data into an Array and say `if(configArray.contains(e.getCause()) { //Do stuff`

Hope this helped!

Comment: For some reason my player won't be added to the array. ( the array stays blank)

Comment: It might be because I put it in an Eventhandler, but i'm not too sure.

Comment: nvm, now it works all of a sudden?

Comment: But now it won't remove it.

Comment: I know why it doesn't but I don't know how to fix it: I have a separate listener class with this code in it, but It has to refer to the main class for the "plugin" it asks for. How can I do that?

Comment: The plugin its asking for is the one right here: "runTaskLater(plugin, 200L);"

Comment: Reply to the post with your class's code, I'm struggling to understand what you mean.

Comment: I have edited the original post, hopefully that can show you what I mean.

Comment: nvm  if ound a way to make it work